# Maximize the solution of an equation containing an integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I have to find `{x,y}` which makes the integral

```
Integrate[(1/(E^((x^2 - 2*x*d + d^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 
                  (r^2/d)*z^2)/(2*(d + r^2)))*
          (Sqrt[d]*(d + r^2)))), {d, 0, Infinity}]
```

equal to `Pi^0.5/Ry`, where `Ry` is a given constant. Among all the possible solutions, I am interested in the one which maximises `y`, with the constraint `y>0`. I have also a good starting point for `y`. The problem has to be solved for different values of `r`, say from 0 to 20, and `Ry`, say from 10^-7 to 10^7. I have set the problem in this way:

```
ranger = {0,0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10};
rangeRy = {10^-6,10^-4,10^-2,10^-1,10^0,10^1,10^2,10^4,10^6};
f[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(1/(E^((x^2 - 2*x*d + d^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 
                    (r^2/d)*z^2)/(2*(d + r^2)))*
            (Sqrt[d]*(d + r^2)))), {d, 0, Infinity}];
solu1 = Table[
  FindMaximum[{y, f1[x, y, 0, r] - Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Ry == 0, 
    y > 0}, {x, {y, Sqrt[(2 Ry)/E]}}], {r, ranger}, {Ry, rangeRy}]
```

Unfortunately, `NIntegrate` fails to converge to the solution for all the values of `r` and `Ry`. Any help?

Comment: `f1` is the same as `f`?

Comment: yes, it si, it was just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is necessary to limit the variables so that there is no division by 0 and so that the integral converges. Secondly, we must make sure that the problem has a solution. Use `ContourPlot` to build  solution of equation `f[x, y, 0, r] - Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Ry == 0`:

```
d0 = 10^-6; r0 = 10^-6; dmax = 20;
ranger = {r0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10};
rangeRy = {10^-6, 10^-4, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, 10^4, 10^6};
f[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ, r_?NumberQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(1/(E^((x^2 - 2*x*d + d^2 + y^2 + 
            z^2 + (r^2/d)*z^2)/(2*(d + r^2)))*(Sqrt[
          d]*(d + r^2)))), {d, d0, dmax}];
Table[With[{r = ranger[[i]], Ry = rangeRy[[5]]}, 
  ContourPlot[
   f[x, y, 0, r] - Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Ry == 0, {x, -1, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"r =", r*1.}, {"Ry =", Ry*1.}}]]], {i, 1, 
  Length[ranger]}]
Table[With[{r = ranger[[i]], Ry = rangeRy[[6]]}, 
  ContourPlot[
   f[x, y, 0, r] - Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Ry == 0, {x, -2, 15}, {y, 0, 4}, 
   PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"r =", r*1.}, {"Ry =", Ry*1.}}]]], {i, 1, 
  Length[ranger]}]
```

[image: fig1]
And so we see that the solution exists for some data. To find the maximum value `y`, use the code:

```
With[{r = 1, Ry = 1}, 
  FindMaximum[
   y /. FindRoot[
     f[x, y, 0, r] - Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Ry == 0, {y, .5}], {x, .5}]] // Quiet
(*{0.537561, {x -> 0.432659}}*)
```

and

```
With[{r = 1, Ry = 10}, 
  FindMaximum[
   y /. FindRoot[f[x, y, 0, r] - Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Ry == 0, {y, 3}], {x, 
    5}]] // Quiet

 (*{3.27002, {x -> 4.02939}}*)
```

Comment: Many thanks!! It works fine, even if I change the integral limit to {d,0,Infinity}, as I need. By the way, why you changed the limits to {d,d0,dmax}?
However, if I delete Quiet from the FindRoot, Mathematica returns a lot of warning messages although the result is seemed to be correctly computed in the end. Can I really discard all these messages?

Comment: Dear Alex Trounev, it would be great if you could help me for two additional questions:
1) I want to express x and y in the ContourPlot in unit of Ry, then on the two axes instead of x and y, I'd like to have x/Ry and y/Ry.
2) it is possible to extract the datapoints of the plotted contour? I mean a matrix containing the x and y, or better the x/Ry and y/Ry, whci represent the contour for each couple of r and Ry?

Comment: @umby 1) Do not use `d=0`, because in the definition of `f` there is `r^2/d`;2) Do not use `Infinity` in numerical calculations; 3) `Quiet` used to cut off meaningless messages arising during the transfer of parameters; 4) What do you want to use `ContourPlot` for?

Comment: I want express the x and y of the ContourPlot in units of Ry, this means I do not want to report the value of x or y but x/Ry and y/Ry. The ContourPlot reports the {x,y} which satisfies the condition f[x, y, 0, r] - Sqrt[\[Pi]]/Ry == 0, I want a ContourPlot which instead reports x/Ry and y/Ry. It is like a rescaling of the coordinate.
Furthermore, I would like to have the couples {x,y} plotted into the ContourPlot as a matrix or a table, as numerical values, let's say.I mean I want to extract the numerical values of the {x,y} plotted in the ContourPlot.
Thank you so much...